# How to Avro Binary encode the JSON String using Apache Avro?

Tags: java, json, binary, arrays, avro

I am trying to avro binary encode my JSON String. Below is my JSON String and I have created a simple method which will do the conversion but I am not sure whether the way I am doing is correct or not?

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
try{
    Schema schema = new Parser().parse((TestExample.class.getResourceAsStream("/3233.avsc")));
    String json="{"+
        "  \"location\" : {"+
        "    \"devices\":["+
        "      {"+
        "        \"did\":\"9abd09-439bcd-629a8f\","+
        "        \"dt\":\"browser\","+
        "        \"usl\":{"+
        "          \"pos\":{"+
        "            \"source\":\"GPS\","+
        "            \"lat\":90.0,"+
        "            \"long\":101.0,"+
        "            \"acc\":100"+
        "          },"+
        "          \"addSource\":\"LL\","+
        "          \"add\":["+
        "            {"+
        "              \"val\":\"2123\","+
        "              \"type\" : \"NUM\""+
        "            },"+
        "            {"+
        "              \"val\":\"Harris ST\","+
        "              \"type\" : \"ST\""+
        "            }"+
        "          ],"+
        "          \"ei\":{"+
        "            \"ibm\":true,"+
        "            \"sr\":10,"+
        "            \"ienz\":true,"+
        "            \"enz\":100,"+
        "            \"enr\":10"+
        "          },"+
        "          \"lm\":1390598086120"+
        "        }"+
        "      }"+
        "    ],"+
        "    \"ver\" : \"1.0\""+
        "  }"+
        "}";

    byte[] avroByteArray = fromJsonToAvro(json,schema);

} catch (Exception ex) {
    // log an exception
}
```

Below method will convert my JSON String to Avro Binary encoded -

```
private static byte[] fromJsonToAvro(String json, Schema schema) throws Exception {

    InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes());
    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(input);   

    Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(schema, din);

    DatumReader<Object> reader = new GenericDatumReader<Object>(schema);
    Object datum = reader.read(null, decoder);


    GenericDatumWriter<Object>  w = new GenericDatumWriter<Object>(schema);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    Encoder e = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(outputStream, null);

    w.write(datum, e);
    e.flush();

    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

Can anyone take a look and let me know whether the way I am trying to avro binary my JSON String is correct or not?

Comment: For what it's worth, the [Apache Avro spec](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.6/spec.html).

Comment: It's not clear what converting JSON "to Avro" would imply, since Avro notation is, per the spec, just a particular set of constraints placed on the format of a JSON string.

Comment: In any event, Apache appears to provide a [set of utilities](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/java/index.html), so it's not clear why you'd need to write your own.

Comment: hmmm.. Not sure I understand that correctly.. I have a JSON string which I am supposed to encode into Avro Binary.. How should I do that? The way I am doing is not correct?

Comment: @HotLicks I've found myself having the same issue, would you mind to point on where to look for these Apache utilities to find the equivalent function/method?

Answer (score 27):

I think OP is correct. This will write Avro records themselves without the schema that would be present if this were an Avro data file.

Here's a couple examples within Avro itself (useful if you are working with files.
    • From JSON to Avro: [DataFileWriteTool](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/java/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/tool/DataFileWriteTool.java)
    • From Avro to JSON: [DataFileReadTool](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/java/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/tool/DataFileReadTool.java)

Here's a complete example going both ways.

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab(group='org.apache.avro', module='avro', version='1.7.7')
])

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumWriter;
import org.apache.avro.io.Decoder;
import org.apache.avro.io.DecoderFactory;
import org.apache.avro.io.Encoder;
import org.apache.avro.io.EncoderFactory;
import org.apache.avro.io.JsonEncoder;

String schema = '''{
  "type":"record",
  "namespace":"foo",
  "name":"Person",
  "fields":[
    {
      "name":"name",
      "type":"string"
    },
    {
      "name":"age",
      "type":"int"
    }
  ]
}'''
String json = "{" +
  "\"name\":\"Frank\"," +
  "\"age\":47" +
"}"

assert avroToJson(jsonToAvro(json, schema), schema) == json


public static byte[] jsonToAvro(String json, String schemaStr) throws IOException {
    InputStream input = null;
    GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord> writer = null;
    Encoder encoder = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = null;
    try {
        Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaStr);
        DatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>(schema);
        input = new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes());
        output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(input);
        writer = new GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord>(schema);
        Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(schema, din);
        encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(output, null);
        GenericRecord datum;
        while (true) {
            try {
                datum = reader.read(null, decoder);
            } catch (EOFException eofe) {
                break;
            }
            writer.write(datum, encoder);
        }
        encoder.flush();
        return output.toByteArray();
    } finally {
        try { input.close(); } catch (Exception e) { }
    }
}

public static String avroToJson(byte[] avro, String schemaStr) throws IOException {
    boolean pretty = false;
    GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = null;
    JsonEncoder encoder = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = null;
    try {
        Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaStr);
        reader = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>(schema);
        InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(avro);
        output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DatumWriter<GenericRecord> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord>(schema);
        encoder = EncoderFactory.get().jsonEncoder(schema, output, pretty);
        Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(input, null);
        GenericRecord datum;
        while (true) {
            try {
                datum = reader.read(null, decoder);
            } catch (EOFException eofe) {
                break;
            }
            writer.write(datum, encoder);
        }
        encoder.flush();
        output.flush();
        return new String(output.toByteArray());
    } finally {
        try { if (output != null) output.close(); } catch (Exception e) { }
    }
}
```

For the sake of completeness, here's an example if you were working with streams (Avro calls these [container files](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Object+Container+Files)) instead of records.  Note that when you go back from JSON to Avro, you don't need to pass the schema.  This is because it is present in the stream.

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab(group='org.apache.avro', module='avro', version='1.7.7')
])

// writes Avro as a http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Object+Container+Files rather than a sequence of records

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream;
import org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumWriter;
import org.apache.avro.io.Decoder;
import org.apache.avro.io.DecoderFactory;
import org.apache.avro.io.Encoder;
import org.apache.avro.io.EncoderFactory;
import org.apache.avro.io.JsonEncoder;


String schema = '''{
  "type":"record",
  "namespace":"foo",
  "name":"Person",
  "fields":[
    {
      "name":"name",
      "type":"string"
    },
    {
      "name":"age",
      "type":"int"
    }
  ]
}'''
String json = "{" +
  "\"name\":\"Frank\"," +
  "\"age\":47" +
"}"

assert avroToJson(jsonToAvro(json, schema)) == json


public static byte[] jsonToAvro(String json, String schemaStr) throws IOException {
    InputStream input = null;
    DataFileWriter<GenericRecord> writer = null;
    Encoder encoder = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = null;
    try {
        Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaStr);
        DatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>(schema);
        input = new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes());
        output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(input);
        writer = new DataFileWriter<GenericRecord>(new GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord>());
        writer.create(schema, output);
        Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(schema, din);
        GenericRecord datum;
        while (true) {
            try {
                datum = reader.read(null, decoder);
            } catch (EOFException eofe) {
                break;
            }
            writer.append(datum);
        }
        writer.flush();
        return output.toByteArray();
    } finally {
        try { input.close(); } catch (Exception e) { }
    }
}

public static String avroToJson(byte[] avro) throws IOException {
    boolean pretty = false;
    GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = null;
    JsonEncoder encoder = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = null;
    try {
        reader = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>();
        InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(avro);
        DataFileStream<GenericRecord> streamReader = new DataFileStream<GenericRecord>(input, reader);
        output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Schema schema = streamReader.getSchema();
        DatumWriter<GenericRecord> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord>(schema);
        encoder = EncoderFactory.get().jsonEncoder(schema, output, pretty);
        for (GenericRecord datum : streamReader) {
            writer.write(datum, encoder);
        }
        encoder.flush();
        output.flush();
        return new String(output.toByteArray());
    } finally {
        try { if (output != null) output.close(); } catch (Exception e) { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `avro-tools` to convert the json file(`{input_file}.json`) to avro file(`{output_file}.avro`) when you know the schema(`{schema_file}.avsc`) of the json file. Just like below:

```
java -jar the/path/of/avro-tools-1.8.1.jar fromjson {input_file}.json   --schema-file {schema_file}.avsc > {output_file}.avro
```

By the way, the contents of `{schema_file}.avsc` file is as belows:

```
{"type": "record",
 "name": "User",
  "fields": [
      {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
      {"name": "favorite_number",  "type": ["int", "null"]},
      {"name": "favorite_color", "type": ["string", "null"]}
  ]
 }
```

[Download avro-tools-1.8.1](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/avro/avro-tools/1.8.1/avro-tools-1.8.1.jar)

[Download others avro-tools](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/avro/avro-tools/)

Answer (score 1):

To add to Keegan's answer, this discussion is likely useful:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/avro-user/201209.mbox/%3CCALEq1Z8s1sfaAVB7YE2rpZ=v3q1V_h7Vm39h0HsOzxJ+qfQRSg@mail.gmail.com%3E

The gist is that there is a special Json schema and you can use JsonReader/Writer to get to and from that. The Json schema you should use is defined here:

https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/trunk/share/schemas/org/apache/avro/data/Json.avsc