# Convert JSON and Avro schema files to Avro format in cdh5.3.0

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera, avro, cloudera-cdh

How can I convert JSON and Avro schema files to Avro format in cdh5.3.0? I could not access Avro-tools jar file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The avro-tools jar is not installed as part CDH.  You can download it from [Cloudera's repository](http://repository.cloudera.com/cloudera/cloudera-repos/org/apache/avro/avro-tools/), or you can invoke the Avro API the tools jar uses yourself, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24460234/160256).

Answer (score 0):

You need to download avro-tools.jar manually... It is not shipped by default.