# Avro to json converter in java

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, avro

I am reading Avro from kafka as a string and I am trying to convert the String avro to Json using java code.

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${kafka.consumer.topics}'.split(',')}", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    void listener(String message, Acknowledgment acknowledgment, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic) throws CacheServiceException, JsonProcessingException {

//some code here
byte[] data = message.getBytes(); //This seems to be the issue

avroToJson(schema,data)


}

//Code to convert avro to json
public String avroToJson(Schema schema, byte[] avroBinary) throws IOException {
        DatumReader<Object> datumReader = new GenericDatumReader<>(schema);
        Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(avroBinary, null);
        Object avroDatum = datumReader.read(null, decoder);
        System.out.println("Initiating loop");
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            DatumWriter<Object> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<>(schema);
            JsonEncoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().jsonEncoder(schema, baos, false);
            writer.write(avroDatum, encoder);
            encoder.flush();
            baos.flush();
            return new String(baos.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }
    }
```

I want to avoid reading data as AVRO from kafka as I am reading data from different topics with different Schemas in same kafka.

Comment: 1) Why are you consuming strings and not using ByteArrayDeserializer? 2) `DecoderFactory` wont work with Confluent serialized Avro messages

Comment: @OneCricketeer I changed it to ByteArrayDeserializer and now I am getting it as byte[]. the code looks as below.

But as you mentioned in point 2, DecoderFactory wont work, can you help me in how can I change my avroToJson function?





@KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${kafka.consumer.topics}'.split(',')}", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
 void listener(byte[] message, Acknowledgment acknowledgment, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic) throws CacheServiceException, JsonProcessingException {

Comment: Also, when using ByteArrayDeserializer to read data as byte array, its reading same as when i try doing message.getBytes() in my earlier code;

Comment: My point is that you don't need `.getBytes()` if you already receive `byte[]`. You need to manually parse out the byte array where the raw avro data exists. https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#wire-format Or you can consume the data using KafkaAvroDeserializer into GenericRecord objects, which `toString` method is JSON-like

Answer (score 0):

There might be some good answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24460234/1858327), but here is how I was able to do this for specific records.

```
MyAvroType avroPojo = ...
var writer = new SpecificDatumWriter<MyAvroType>(avroPojo.getSchema());
var outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
var encoder = EncoderFactory.get().jsonEncoder(avroPojo.getSchema(), outputStream);
writer.write(event, encoder);
encoder.flush(); // If you get null strings this may be what you're missing
String s = outputStream.toString();
```

In addition to the "normal" binary encoding, the JSON encoding is also part of Avro's [specification](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.11.1/specification/#json-encoding) but there just don't seem to be as many examples of it around.

> I want to avoid reading data as AVRO from kafka as I am reading data from different topics with different Schemas in same kafka.

Avro is not a "self describing" format like JSON is. Put simply that means that the serialized (binary) format does not have field names. Something like `{name: Bob, age: 30}` is encoded something like `Bob30`. It's not quite that simple of course, but the point remains that without the schema there is no way to get the field names from a binary Avro record. So there is no way to skip "reading data as Avro" and go straight to JSON because the information is simply not there.

Answer (score -1):

Avro is used to validate your data against the schema. if you don't want this, simply remove Avro and use only Kafka. From the producer, side send json data instead of avro serialized data.

Comment: yeah, but in my case, the producer is a different team and I cannot control the producer format as other consumers too use the same kafka topic as their source.

Comment: Please proceed without avro in that case otherwise design a wrapper avro and pass data as a string or use something generic.